# how to transfer string to number in javascript from nested array

Tags: javascript

```
const detail = [{"User": {"id": 1, "name":"jack", "address":[{"zip":"333"}]}}];
```

I want to change zip string to number using javascript used through map it does not work please guide

```
detail.map((item) => {
 return item.address.map(e => Number(e.zip)
})
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that isn't working?

Comment: `detail.forEach(d => d.User.address.forEach(a => a.zip = +a.zip ))`

Comment: The goal here is to use `.map()` right? That's why you've mentioned _mapping_ in your question?

Comment: X/Y problem if not. Why use a map to change something when forEach can do it? Waste of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep your array update immutable, which can be useful for a number of reasons, such as performing a state update in React, reducing the number of side-effects your code has, if you're writing functional style code, etc., then what you want is a mapping operation (as you've mentioned in your question).

When mapping over `detail`, you're mapping over the outermost objects. You need to recreate each object (and its inner objects), so that you can then finally update the inner `address` array property:

```js
const detail = [{"User": {"id": 1, "name":"jack", "address": [{"zip":"333"}]}}];

const res = detail.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  User: {
    ...obj.User,
    address: obj.User.address.map(address => ({...address, zip: +address.zip}))
  }
}));
console.log(res);
```

By using the spread syntax (`...`) above, we're able to create a new outer object with `...obj`, with an updated `User` key, that holds a new object with all the existing properties of the user object (due to `...obj.User`). This new `User` object then has an updated `address` property, which holds the mapped address objects. By creating new objects, we can avoid updating those in the original `detail` array (thus keeping the original `detail` array and its objects available as is for reuse if needed).

---

If you don't mind updating your original array's objects (instead of returning a new array with new objects), then using a regular `for`/`.forEach()` loop instead of `.map()` as shown in the comments below your question or as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) might be more suitable and performant. This will directly modify your objects inside of your `detail` array instead of returning a new array:

```js
const detail = [{"User": {"id": 1, "name":"jack", "address": [{"zip":"333"}]}}];

for(const {User: {address}} of detail)
  for(const addr of address)
    addr.zip = +addr.zip;

console.log(detail);
```